# D3 code not working in Chrome possibly due to SyntaxError (DOM Exception 12)

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, d3.js, drupal

A page using D3 javascript is working in Safari and Firefox but is throwing a DOM Exception 12 in the iCab browser. I used iCab because I haven't been able to view the console.log messages in Chrome. The page creates a map using D3 and the map is drawn properly but code that inserts text into it isn't working. The data is obtained by the following code

> d3.json("/sites/default/d3_files/json/toronto-wards.json", function(error,wards) {
>     d3.json("/postcards-json", function(error, postcards) {
>     if(error){myFunc2 (error);}

The first JSON call is used to draw the map and the second JSON has the data to insert into the map. If anyone knows how to view the console messages the page is http://www.stopplastics.ca/toronto-postcard-tallies-values: In case it is relevant, I am creating the second JSON using a Drupal view.

Comment: I've managed to get some clues because Chrome displays errors other than my console.log messages and it appears that Chrome considers some of my object references which are valid in Safari, as undefined,

Comment: Perhaps this is the cause of the problem. I get this error in Chrome immediately after reading the JSON file. console.log ("event -> "+postcards.nodes[0].node.event); // "tally" in Safari "TypeError: Cannot read property 'node' of undefined" in Chrome. Is there a limit to the levels in a nested JSON file?

Comment: I have created a new version at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48646465/problems-reading-json-file-in-d3-javascript-in-some-not-all-browsers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by the fact that the JSON file was empty under some circumstances, I have fixed that problem and the chart displays correctly now.