# Problems reading JSON file in D3 javascript in some (not all) browsers

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, drupal-7

I get this error in Chrome immediately after reading a JSON file. It works correctly in Safari and Firefox.

> console.log ("event -> "+ postcards.nodes[0].node.event); // "tally" in Safari "TypeError: Cannot read property 'node' of undefined" in Chrome.<

Is there a limit to the levels in a nested JSON file? I generate the JSON from a Drupal view. Here here is the start:

```
{"nodes":[{"node":{"w1":"","w2":"1","w3":"","w4":"", ...<
```

Here is the Javascript:

```
d3.json(
  "/sites/default/d3_files/json/toronto-wards.json", 
  function(error,wards) {
    d3.json("/postcards-json", function(error, postcards) {
      console.log ("event -> "+ postcards.nodes[0].node.event); // tally in Safari
```

I'm using macOS and my friends using Windows get the same error in Firefox.

As per request here is what I think is the XHR message:

```
d3.min.js:1 XHR finished loading: GET "http://www.stopplastics.ca/postcards-json".
```

Comment: What do you mean by preview?

Comment: Response: {"nodes":[]} Preview {nodes: []}
nodes [] - is that what you want? Did you see the XHR message I posted above? and would you like to see the headers?

Comment: I don't know how to see headers in Safari but I know that data is returned since the console message shows data "tally" in the first row: console.log ("event -> "+ postcards.nodes[0].node.event); // "tally" in Safari

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164637/discussion-between-patriciaw-and-hmr).

Comment: I found out how to display XHR message - here is the start: {
    "nodes": [
        {
            "node": {
                "w1": "",
                "w2": "1",
                "w3": "",
                "w4": "",

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by the Drupal view not being created correctly. Nothing to do with the Chrome browser.

Answer (score 0):

Does the following work for you?

```
Promise.all(
  d3.json("/sites/default/d3_files/json/toronto-wards.json"),
  d3.json("/postcards-json")
)
.then(
  function([wards,postcards]) {
    console.log ("event -> "+ postcards.nodes[0].node.event); // tally in Safari
```

Some browsers may not support deconstructing arrays so probably better to try the following for older browsers (non Chrome and Firefox):

```
Promise.all(
  d3.json("/sites/default/d3_files/json/toronto-wards.json"),
  d3.json("/postcards-json")
)
.then(
  function(results) {
    var wards=results[0],postcards=results[1];
    console.log ("event -> "+ postcards.nodes[0].node.event);
  }
);
```

According to the comments your drupal end point providing the JSON needs authentication so gives you empty data when you're not loged in.

Error has maybe nothing to do with the browser used but depends if you're loged in or not.

Comment: I have dumb question but would it not be better to discuss in the discussion?

Comment: Dumb question: where should the "then(" end?

Comment: When I ran this with closing bracket after the console.log, I got this error: Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: Totally puzzled. I decided to download the JSONView extension to validate my JSON file. This required me to log into chrome. Once I installed the extension but had not activated it my page started to work properly and the preview is: {nodes: [{,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…}]}
nodes
:
[{,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…}]

Comment: I discovered that my JSON file that was created by a Drupal view was not displaying properly if I was not logged in as the Drupal administrator. I do not know if this was always the case but I do not want to pursue this until I can get a working view, Thanks for your help HMR.

Comment: @PatriciaW Ok, was going to ask if drupal data was depending on authentication but guess you've figured it out. Sorry I didn't think of this earlier.

Comment: No need to apologize. I never thought of it because the view shouldn't depend upon authorization. I regard that as a defect so I am pursuing that. Thanks for your help.